# Control Width of columns in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone please let me know how can we control the width of column in bootstrap 3. I have tried with setting the bAutoWidth: false and still no luck..Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean control width of column?

Comment: maybe changing it through the css: col-sm-6{width:75%}

Comment: how do you try it? you need to provide the codes to share (at least, to let all know what you have done with it)

Comment: Like jsg said, you can use <div class="row">, and inside that <div class="col-md-6"> etc. Bootstrap divides page into 12 vertical columns. so col-md-6 or col-xs-6 means, a div which spans 6 columns. md, xs etc stand for size of screen. (medium, extra-small etc)

Comment: also another alternative is nesting columns:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Please include the relevant source code, and what your problem is with it.